# Can I set refresh intervals for my odbc connected Access Database?

Tags: ms-access, odbc

I have an Access database that connects to a program's tables via odbc. Is there a way to set refresh intervals in Access so that I don't have to do it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using a timer event:

Edit the (sub)form, select the form object.

On the property sheet, under events set the Timer Interval to 60000 (it's in milliseconds)
in the On Timer event, add an event that does a:

```
Me.Refresh
```

I'd probably wrap it in an if statement to stop it messing up edits:

```
If Not Me.Dirty Then 
    Me.Refresh
End If
```

If you have other controls on the sub-form that source data from tables that may change (like combo-boxes that list products, where someone may add a new product) you probably want to use a Me.Requery rather than a simple refresh.

lastly, if the flashing of the screen during updating is a problem, look at:

```
Application.Echo = False    ' turn screen refreshing off
Me.Refresh
Application.Echo = True    ' turn refreshing back on
```

Comment: really appreciate the feedback. Our systems are down so I haven't been able to confirm that it works. I was wondering, though - if the DB is refreshing every ~15 minutes, is there a significant increase in resources being used? The query will ultimately be connected to an excel workbook and I'm concerned that Access and/or Excel won't be able to handle it. I know I'm leaving out some key information pertaining to bandwidth and computer capabilities, but I'm hoping the answer will be either be 'yes, big resources drain'; or 'no, minimal impact'. Thanks!

Comment: if you refresh every 15 mins, you should not see a significant drain.  
If you did it every minute, you'd probably notice a problem.  Note that if you attach the timer to a form, when the form isn't open, there will be no timer events, so no chance of resource drain.